# Can you feed urandom to dd for wiping a drive but skip every other block to speed it up?

Tags: linux, security, hard-disk, dd, random

I've been wiping a large number of old laptops for donation/recycling. To do so I boot up to a Linux live CLI from USB or CD and use `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda status=progress` to overwrite the data on them. My problem is this takes a very long time for each laptop, especially as some of them are extremely old and slow. Is it possible to tell dd to overwrite only every other block instead? If so will this effectively cut the time required to process in half? And what would be the best command to accomplish this?

My company has no real policy on data security and most of these don't contain particularly sensitive information to begin with. Nevertheless would executing this still make it possible to recover information from the drives without too much effort?

Comment: Why not use `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M status=progress`? To recover information from a zeroed disk requires very specialized tools. The problem with only overwriting every other block is that it means there is almost a 50% chance that some short sequence of data is left intact, such as a plain text password or an ssh key.

Comment: Soon providing Perl approach to this.

Comment: The effective time per laptop will be cut in half if you work with twice as many laptops in parallel.

Answer (score 3):

I would not suggest "wiping" Hard Drives (especially SSDs) by writing blocks via `dd` to the drive. Instead, I would use the ATA Secure Erase Command (if supported by the drive). See [Kernel.org Wiki - ATA Secure Erase](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase) for further details.

Comment: That page suggests the Secure Erase command can take hours to run. How might that speed up the process versus using the dd command?

Answer (score 0):

Preamble: take it as a prototype, just an example to promote discussion.

I modified a [Perl script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37463053/3523425) that I use to make faster md5sum for huge files (>TB), and made a (really rough) bash script to perform some operation an then recall it.
The basic idea behind this is:

1. Wipe disk partition table
2. Create single partition spanning all disk and format it
3. Mount partition and fill it instantly (fallocate) with a single file
4. Crucial part here: process file dividing it in fixed amount of blocks and overwrite 4kB with random data (just numbers in this case).

A lot to do from here, refine blocks numbers and bytes to process, shift blocks randomly, adopt a cryptosecure library for rand generation, adopt defensive scripting etc...

But enough small talk for a prototype.

Here's perlwipe.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Time::HiRes qw[ time ];

sub round_potenza {
    my $rounded = 0;
    my ($x,$p) = (@_,2);
    my $log = log($x)/log($p);
    $log = int($log+1) if $log != int($log);
    if ( abs($x-($p**$log))> abs($x-($p**int($log-1))) ) {
    $rounded = $p**($log-1);
    } else {
    $rounded = $p**$log;
    }
    return $rounded;
}

sub quickWipe {
    my $fh = shift;
    my $charset = shift;
    my $pos = 0;
    my $size = -s $ARGV[0];
    my $chunkraw = int($size/50000);
    my $chunk = round_potenza($chunkraw);
    printf $chunk;
    until( eof $fh ) {
        seek $fh, $pos, 0;
        my $garbage = rand(10);
        read( $fh, my $block, 4096 ) or last;
        print $fh $garbage;
        $pos += $chunk;
    }
}

open FH, '+<', $ARGV[0] or die $!;
printf "Processing $ARGV[0] : %u bytes\n", -s FH;

my $start = time;
my $wipe = quickWipe( *FH );
printf "Fast Wipe took %.6f seconds\n", time() - $start;
```

And this is Bash script wipeskipping.sh, pretty self-explanatory:

```
#!/bin/bash
#HANDLE WITH CARE!
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "You like to live dangerously."
        exit 0
else
        DEVICE="/dev/$1"
        PARTITION="1"
        PARTEDCMD="/tmp/partedcmd"
        MOUNTPOINT="/tmp/mountpoint"
        /sbin/wipefs -a -f $DEVICE
        echo mklabel gpt> $PARTEDCMD
        echo mkpart primary 0% 100%>> $PARTEDCMD
        echo quit>> $PARTEDCMD
        /sbin/parted $DEVICE <$PARTEDCMD
        /sbin/mkfs.ext4 -F $DEVICE$PARTITION
        mkdir $MOUNTPOINT
        mount $DEVICE$PARTITION $MOUNTPOINT
        /usr/bin/fallocate -l 5000G $MOUNTPOINT/sparsefile
        /usr/bin/perl perlwipe.pl $MOUNTPOINT/sparsefile
fi
```

At the present time, with all limitations and issues, all this is about 10 times faster than dd from urandom source in my lab.

Usage: **./wipeskipping.sh sd[X]**